# Why performance is improved when thread count is increased than the hardware-possible thread count?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

In my PC, I have 16 logical cores(multiprocessing.cpu_count()=16). I have an application which has around 2000 independent processes. I used multi-threading with different thread counts and the results are as follows.

---

### Threads | Total Time(s)

8 | 4225 (~ 70 min)

16 | 2733 (~ 46 min)

32 | 2156 (~ 35 min)

64 | 2123 (~ 35 min)

Theoretically, I should get the best results when thread count is 16. And I should get the same results even if the thread count is increased above 16. But I'm getting the best results when the thread count is increased to 32. And the results looks to be unchanged above that count. What is the reason for that?

Comment: Not everything is CPU bound, i.e. your threads do not utilise your cores 100% all the time. By running multiple threads per core you are making use of that idle time.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, Python cannot run more than one thread concurrently (because of GIL), so any threads that run Python code at 100% CPU usage (e.g. pure calculation) will always degrade in performance with more threads.

Getting *any* performance increases from threads means you have some I/O in your code that is being waited on, which makes your thread's CPU utilisation fall under 100%. Increasing the number of threads allows the CPU to fill up those gaps.

Comment: Your first paragraph is only partly true. Especially with I/O the GIL can and will be released.

Comment: @KlausD. I intended "any threads that run Python code at 100% CPU usage (e.g. pure calculation)" to cover it. Apparently I failed. What I wanted to say is, IO makes threads wait, so they are not "running" in that sense. You are welcome to reformulate the sentence if it will be more understandable.

Comment: @Amadan, processes I'm running in my code are independent. So, I don't have any code which is waiting for any I/O.